# Junit EasyMock, resultSet.getBigDecimal("") returns null value

Tags: java, junit

I have built a mock object using EasyMock and PowerMock. When I set expect behavior for getBigDecimal("") method it is returning `null`.

```
@Test
public void getProductPriceContractInfo_v1_1Test() throws Exception{

    GetSPDProductPricePersistor productPricePersistor = new GetSPDProductPricePersistor();
    ProductPriceAndContractRequest_v1_1 productPriceAndContractRequest = new ProductPriceAndContractRequest_v1_1();
   /* set all request parameters in productPriceAndContractRequest --- */

    PowerMock.mockStatic(DataSourceManager.class); 
    DataSourceManager dBAccessor = PowerMock.createMock(DataSourceManager.class);
    EasyMock.expect(DataSourceManager.getInstance()).andReturn(dBAccessor).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(DataSourceManager.freeConnection((Connection)EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject(),
            EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(true);

    Connection connection = EasyMock.createMock(Connection.class);  
    PreparedStatement ps = EasyMock.createMock(PreparedStatement.class);    

    EasyMock.expect(dBAccessor.getConnection(EasyMock.anyString())).andReturn(connection).anyTimes();       

    connection.close();
    connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
    EasyMock.expect(connection.prepareStatement((String)EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(ps);

    ResultSet rs = EasyMock.createMock(ResultSet.class);
    EasyMock.expect(rs.next()).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(rs.next()).andReturn(false);
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getString("")).andReturn("Y").times(4);
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn((BigDecimal) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn((BigDecimal) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal((""))).andReturn((BigDecimal) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getDate("")).andReturn((java.sql.Date) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn(BigDecimal.TEN).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn((BigDecimal) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(987654L)).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getInt("")).andReturn(5).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getString("")).andReturn("").anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getString("")).andReturn("").anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(rs.getString("")).andReturn("").anyTimes();

    EasyMock.expect(ps.executeQuery()).andReturn(rs);   // returning ResultSet          
    EasyMock.expect(ps.executeQuery()).andReturn(rs);


    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));  
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));  
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));  
    ps.setString(EasyMock.anyInt(),String.valueOf(EasyMock.anyInt()));
    ps.close();

    PowerMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes();  

    PowerMock.replay(DataSourceManager.class);
    PowerMock.replay(dBAccessor);
    EasyMock.replay(connection);
    EasyMock.replay(ps);
    EasyMock.replay(rs);


    ProductPriceAndContractResponse_v1_1 response = (ProductPriceAndContractResponse_v1_1)productPricePersistor.getProductPriceContractInfo_v1_1(productPriceAndContractRequest);
    assertNotNull(response);
}
```

When I debug it,

```
   public BaseResponse getProductPriceContractInfo_v1_1 (parameters) {
        Connection connection = null;

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            connection = getConnection(ProductPricingInfoConstants.SPD_ODS_DATASOURCE_JNDI); // class method call
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery.toString());
            ps.setString(1, custNo);
            ps.setString(2, divNo);
            //made changes for 14.5 CI Release--START
             ps.setString(3, custNo);
             ps.setString(4, divNo); //PCRD-15.2 Specialty Online Requirements-Batch I

             int index = 5; //PCRD-15.2 Specialty Online Requirements-Batch I

            //made changes for 14.5 CI Release--END
            for (String cin : itmLst) {
                ps.setString(index++, cin);
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (null != rs) {
                ContractInfo contractInfo;
                ProductPriceInfo productPriceInfo;

                while (rs.next()) {
                    productPriceInfo = new ProductPriceInfo();

                    String str = rs.getString("")
                    productPriceInfo.setAltProductContract();

                    int num = rs.getInt("");

                    BigDecimal cntrNumber = rs.getBigDecimal("");
                    productPriceInfo.setContractNumber(cntrNumber.toString());
}
```

I got expected value in `num` and `str`  variable but got `null` value in `cntrNumber` variable.

Comment: why do you use easyMock and powerMock as from what I see you don't need to mock privates or statics? Can you add the sample code?

Comment: There's no point mocking objects for a test to directly invoke methods on those mocks from a test (unless you're developing a Mocking API).  That aside, please include the code that is printing the output including the invocations of the `ResultSet` gets

Comment: Also, in the code you've shown, you don't appear to be mocking any methods that return the `ResultSet` from the `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @olimpiu Thanks for your response, I have added rest code please check.

Comment: @nick - Thanks nick for giving me your valuable time, please check method is returning the ResultSet from the PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 2):

Only one expectation of `getBigDecimal` will ever be used as specified by:

```
EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn((BigDecimal) EasyMock.anyObject()).anyTimes();
```

The `anyTimes` method is saying this can be invoked an indeterminate number of times and therefore no of the other expectations on `getBigDecimal` will be used.

Your test doesn't call `EasyMock.verify` when finished.  If it did the test would fail because the expectations are not met, thus highlighting this problem.

The reason `getBigDecimal` is returning a `null` is because `EasyMock.anyObject()` returns a `null`.  The method `EasyMock.anyObject()` isn't intended to be used as a return value, as specified in the documentation it creates a *matcher* that will match any `Object` parameter passed to a method.

As an aside, tests like this are pretty much useless - they are simply testing the code invokes the methods specified in the method being tested, which you can be pretty sure Java will do.

You should test actual database integration with Acceptance tests that run as a suite separate from your unit tests.

Comment: If I return the value like this EasyMock.expect(rs.getBigDecimal("")).andReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(987654L)).anyTimes();  its still returning null value, Can you please suggest me what should be the return value,

Comment: Did you read the bit about `anyTimes`?  If you make the first expectation return a `BigDecimal`, it will work